# Como criar um formulário e autenticar usuário Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, login, autenticação, django-templates

Boa noite a todos.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em django apenas para fins didáticos e não consegui encontrar uma solução para meu problema.

Não consegui gerar um formulário para o usuário logar-se e muito menos autenticar este usuário.

Já consegui gerar um formulário para cadastro, mas me falta autenticar o usuário.

O que devo fazer?

Obs: Versão do Django: 1.10.4

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import CadastroForm

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')


def cadastro(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CadastroForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        form = CadastroForm()

    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', {'form': form})


def entrar(request):

    return render(request, 'entrar.html', {})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.


class Cadastro(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Cadastro


class CadastroForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cadastro
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'username', 'password')
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px; width: 500px;">
  <h2 align="center">Login</h2>
  <form action="{% url 'blog:index' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form_login %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="{{field.id_for_label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
        {{field|add_class:'form-control'}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="submit" align="center" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Para quem estiver interessado em ver o repositório do projeto: [GitHub](https://github.com/VictorAlessander/django-study)

Answer (score 2):

Use "the django authentication framework".
Django traz "embutido" um framework de autenticacao com handlers de autenticacao, sessoes, permissoes e grupos de usuarios.
O sistema de autenticacao ja inclui views para acoes usuais como login, logout, alteração de senha, etc.
O pacote em que o sistema esta contido é: django.contrib.auth, por default ele é incluido em seu settings quando vc faz um startproject

O framework de autenticacao inclui os seguintes models:

- User: Model para usuarios com os campos principais:  username,
  password, email, first_name, last_name e is_active.
- group: Nomes dos grupos para categorização dos usuarios
- permission: Autoexplicativo

View para o login

Nossa view para o login deverá acionar um form de login, então vamos criar primeiro um novo form em forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Agora vamos criar o codigo da view propriamente dita:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],
                   password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated',
                        successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'sua-app/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Agora precisamos criar o url pattern para essa view, em urls.py dentro da sua aplicacao:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

...
urlpaterns += [url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),]
```

A view agora pode ser acessada pela URL, mas ainda falta criar a template para esta view, o exemplo de template que reproduzo abaixo estende uma base (base.html). No diretorio de templates de sua aplicação crie o arquivo login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    <p>Use of formulário abaixo:</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
{%  endblock %}
```

Ok!
Agora, se ainda não criou o superuser, crie-o, rode seu projeto entre em admin e crie um usuário, em seguida aponte o browser para o login da sua app, algo como http://127.0.0.1:8000/sua-app/login e voce deverá ver o a template renderizada com o form de login.

Observação:
Voce pode fazer muito mais, como por exemplo um link para logout, redefinição de senhas, etc. A explanação aqui é uma adaptação de exemplos do capitulo 2 do livro: Django By Example.