# Como bloquear login de usuário com determinado "status" no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou utilizando o Django 1.11 e views baseadas em classes. Meu modelo de usuário está customizado e nele tenho um campo "status" onde tem "ativado, bloqueado e desativado". Gostaria de saber como posso permitir o login somente dos usuários que estejam ativados, e os demais sejam barrados.

Desde já valeu a todos !

Comment: [Eis a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187235/7412), embora com o titulo da pergunta totamente diferente, e, talvez vc acabe vendo que o proprio django te fornece mecanismos para o status do usuário. Preste atenção no meio do codigo da view, tem exatamente o q vc quer: `if user.is_active: ...`

Comment: Não é isso que quero ainda. Mas obrigado. No meu caso tenho 3 status que a nível de modelo são um enum (regra de negócio). No caso do método is_active acredito que não seja para esse propósito.

Comment: Vc pode ter quantos status quiser, é só estender as tabelas `auth_user`, `auth_user_groups ` e `auth_user_user_permissions`